# How do I test a meta-function without requiring the parameter function to be mutable?

Tags: testing, rust, automated-tests, higher-order-functions

I've written a function `save` that takes a function as a parameter:

```rust
fn save(method:&dyn Fn(&'static str)) {
    method("Hello world");
}

fn print(string:&'static str) {
    println!("{}", string);
}

fn main() {
    save(&print)
}
```

This works great! But I now want to test `save`. The best way I see of doing this is to use a `FnMut`:

```rust
fn save(method: &mut dyn FnMut(&'static str)) {
    method("Hello world");
}

fn print(string: &'static str) {
    println!("{}", string);
}

fn main() {
    save(&mut print)
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn save_test() {
        let actual = {
            let mut actual = String::new();
            let mut method = |string: &'static str| {
                actual = format!("{}{}", actual, string);
            };
            save(&mut method);
            save(&mut method);
            actual
        };
        let expected = "Hello worldHello world".to_string();

        assert_eq!(actual, expected);
    }
}
```

This still works and accomplishes everything I want! But now I have to use mutable references whenever I `call` save. While this doesn't affect functionality, it does obfuscate the code. Is there a better way to accomplish the same result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html) to get interior mutability, allowing you to mutable a variable through a shared reference. It's perfect for testing things like this:

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use std::cell::RefCell;
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn save_test() {
        let actual = {
            // wrap "actual" in a RefCell, which allows for interior mutability
            let actual = RefCell::new(String::new());
            let method = |string: &'static str| {
                // mutably borrow the string at runtime
                // (can panic in already borrowed, but not a problem here)
                let mut actual = actual.borrow_mut();

                // append string (equivalent to your format!() but can be more
                // efficient)
                actual.push_str(string);
            };

            save(&method);
            save(&method);

            // move string out of RefCell
            actual.into_inner()
        };
        let expected = "Hello worldHello world".to_string();

        assert_eq!(actual, expected);
    }
}
```

[Run in Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=71393f7a427f542511ff3b52c371f99b)

Answer (score 2):

Just assert inside:

```rust
fn save(method: impl Fn(&'static str)) {
    method("Hello world");
}

#[test]
fn save_test() {
    let check = |result| {
        assert_eq!(result, "Hello world");
    };
    save(check);
    save(check);
}
```

(Doesn't ensure the function is call, it's a trade off)

Comment: This is a good answer for a lot of cases, including the pet example I provided. I accepted the other answer because it is more generally applicable and was what I actually used in my code.

Comment: In particular, the actual `save` function in my code is used to interact with a MySql database. Its `method` parameter, which is called multiple times per call to `save`, takes an insert query as input and returns the resulting row's primary id. Therefore, the stub `check`, needs to be able to validate different insert queries and increment the id it's returning.